# VLAN tag is being removed on veth interface

Tags: c, sockets, bridge, vlan, linux-namespaces

I have two Linux `namespaces` with a bridge between them, and two pairs of `veth` pipes connecting namespaces with the bridge:

ns1 ----- Bridge ----- ns2

I didn't add any VLAN sub-interfaces over veth.

An application I run on ns1 open a raw `AF_PACKET` socket and constructs a vlan tagged ARP probe packet, then does `recvfrom()` in thread. So far so good, tcpdump shows it correctly, vlan tag is stripped off when it leaves the bridge towards ns2, and the tag is added (PVID) when a frame is leaving the bridge towards ns1.

However what `recvfrom` reads is an ARP reply, which means something on ns1 side has stripped the VLAN tag. The reason I need to read the tag is to know which ID was the packet tagged with by the bridge.

Then I did on ns1:

```
% ethtool -K veth0 rxvlan off
```

it didn't help though. What else could be removing the tag? What am I missing?